# Change browser language

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

I'm currently implementing a small web view in my application.

Everything is working fine with `CefSharp` but I have a small problem.

It seems like `CefSharp` is using something like `en-US` as the default browser language. I can't find any information about how to change the language that is used.

For my web view I need the browser to be set on a German language.

Is there any way to do that? Can the language be changed? If yes, how?

Comment: Search for `Locale` in the project source, should be a property on `CefSettings`.

Answer (score 10):

You can change the language that:

```
CefSettings settingsBrowser = new CefSettings();
settingsBrowser.Locale = "de";

Cef.Initialize(settingsBrowser);
```

Comment: Don't forget to include the `locales/<locale>.pak` into your application.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

Implement [IRequestHandler](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp/IRequestHandler.cs) ([example here](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp.Example/RequestHandler.cs)) and implement OnBeforeResourceLoad this way:

```
// Other implementations here ...

CefReturnValue OnBeforeResourceLoad(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, IRequestCallback callback)
{
    var headers = request.Headers;
    headers.Add("Accept-Language", "de,de-DE");        
    return CefReturnValue.Continue;
}
```

Then set the RequestHandler of your browser instance with a new instance of this Implementation.

Comment: You need to reassign headers after changing it as per the doco http://cefsharp.github.io/api/51.0.0/html/P_CefSharp_IRequest_Headers.htm

Comment: Also that won't localise your app, change the locale to change the context menu etc

Answer (score 1):

via CefSettings you can change locale of the browser but you also need to change default language of "Accept-Language" header. The simplest way:

```
CefBrowserSettings browser_settings;
CefString(&browser_settings.accept_language_list) = L"de,de-DE";
```